# need help accessing information in embedded classes

Tags: java, class

Long story short, I want a method to return two items. I think I learned the best way to do that is with an embedded class. I'm having difficulty with the structure and syntax though, as well as how to access the info.

Really what I want to do is have a method return an array String[] and a String. If you can think of an easier way to do this I'd be really interested in hearing about it.

Thank you so much for you help

Thanks

```
import java.util.*;

public class test
{

public test()
{
}

public class SQLarguments //embedded class
{
    String[] columns;
    String table;

    public  SQLarguments(String table, String... columns) 
    {
        this.table = table;
        this.columns = columns;
    }
}

public SQLarguments arguments(String table, String... columns)
{
    SQLarguments testArgs = new SQLarguments(table,columns);        
    return testArgs;
}

public static void main(String[] args)  
{
    test t1 = new test();
    t1.arguments("table","col 1","col 2", "col 3");
    System.out.println(.arguments[0]);
    System.out.println("test");
}//end main

}//end class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reorganized your code to put the Test methods together and the SQLarguments methods together.  I changed the name of the main class to Test, because class names in Java start with a capital letter.

I added two getter methods to your SQLarguments class, so you can retrieve the values you set in the constructor.  I used one of the getter methods in your Test main method.

Here's the code:

```
public class Test {

    public Test() {

    }

    public SQLarguments arguments(String table, String... columns) {
        SQLarguments testArgs = new SQLarguments(table, columns);
        return testArgs;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1 = new Test();
        SQLarguments arguments = 
                t1.arguments("table","col 1","col 2", "col 3");
        System.out.println(arguments.getColumns()[0]);
        System.out.println("test");
    }   //end main

    public class SQLarguments {     // Embedded class
        String[]    columns;
        String      table;

        public SQLarguments(String table, String... columns) {
            this.table = table;
            this.columns = columns;
        }

        public String[] getColumns() {
            return columns;
        }

        public String getTable() {
            return table;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to do.  Thanks so much you're awesome!